# Python list mutation after copying

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability

```
def mutation(input_list):
  list_copy = input_list[:]
  list_copy[0] = 10
  input_list = list_copy

# Correctly mutates
sample_list = [0,1,2]
sample_copy = sample_list[:]
sample_copy[0] = 10
sample_list = sample_copy
print(sample_list)

# Incorrectly mutates
sample_list = [0,1,2]
mutation(sample_list)
print(sample_list)
```

In the top snippet of code, I've made a copy of a list and modified it. I then set the original to the copy and then it works. 
What confuses me is why doing this process outside of a function works but if I were to do it inside a function (the 2nd snippet of code), it fails?

For reference, the code returns:

```
[10, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2]
```

EDIT: I know that calling `input_list[0] = 10` works. I just want to know what makes this different from what I showed above all in memory?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference.

Comment: Highly suggested reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.  This should give you all the answers you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: It worked just fine. The `sample_list` in the global namespace did not get mutates.your last line in the function effectively does nothing. `input_list = list_copy` it simply assigns to the local variable `input_list`, but that doesn't affect anything in the global scope. Please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `mutation`, `input_list` starts out pointing at the same object as `sample_list`, but later you make it point at `list_copy`.
`sample_list` is not modified. It is still pointing at the original object.

When you do it outside of the function you change `sample_list` to point to the new object before printing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that using the built-in function `id` to show the object ID will help here. If the ID of two variable names gives the same result then they refer to the same object; otherwise the objects are different.

```
>>> def mutation(input_list):
...     print(id(input_list))
...     list_copy = input_list[:]
...     print(id(list_copy))
...     input_list = list_copy
...     print(id(input_list))
...     
>>> a = list(range(10))
>>> print(id(a))
140737233394376
>>> mutation(a)
140737233394376
140737233289160
140737233289160
```

In the above, we see that after `input_list = list_copy`, the name `input_list` refers to identically the same object in memory as `list_copy`, which means it no longer refers to the list given as the function argument. This is why the mutation you expect does not work - you are modifying an entirely different object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you sets new value for `input_list` which is local variable of `mutation` function.

The simplest solution is changing value of first element of list passed as argument:

```
def mutation(input_list):
    input_list[0] = 10
```

Otherwise you can write function which changes value of global variable called `sample_list`

```
def mutation():
    global sample_list
    list_copy = sample_list[:]
    list_copy[0] = 10
    sample_list = list_copy
```